# My timer doesn't seem to be ticking and no errors are being thrown in the loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does anyone have an idea of whats going wrong here, i'm not getting any errors in the console window and the click event works but it just changes to the time and never actually ticks here is my code...

EDIT - This does compile and run fine, when you click the label the text changes to a timer and should begin to tick. THe click event works fine, you can click the label it then turns into the specidifed start time 4:59 but freezes and does not tick.

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import *
from Queue import *
from threading import *

class exp_timer(Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    c = Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Exp Bonus")
    self.master.geometry("350x250")

    self.five_exp = Label(c,text = "5% exp")

    self.five_exp.grid(row=0,column=0)   

    self.five_exp.bind("<Button-1>",self.five_exp_click)

    self.minutes = 4
    self.sec = 59


  def my_label_timer(minutes,sec):
    sec -= 1
    if sec < 60:
        sec -= 1
    if sec == 0:
        sec = 59
        minutes -=1
    if minutes == 0 and sec == 0:
      return self.five_exp.configure(text="5% exp")

  def five_exp_start(self):
    self.five_exp.configure(text = "{0}:{1:02}".format(self.minutes,self.sec))
    self.five_exp.update()
    self.minutes = self.my_label_timer(self.minutes)
    self.sec = self.my_label_timer(self.sec)
  def five_exp_click(self,event):
    self.five_exp.configure(self.five_exp_start())
    self.five_exp.update()



exp_timer().mainloop()
```

Comment: It's very unclear from that code what you are trying to achieve here.  What is supposed to happen when you click the label?

Comment: Sorry about that , yeah its just a click event linked to the label. When you click the label the the text should turn into a timer and it does but it doesnt tick.

Comment: And the timer should count down from 4:59 to 0:00?

Comment: correct, sorry about the lacking info i added an edit

Comment: not the only problem but `sec == 59` should be `sec = 59`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of problems with your code, so I've had a go at re-jigging it for you.

This should meet your needs:

```
class exp_timer(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        c = Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Exp Bonus")
        self.master.geometry("350x250")
        self.label = Label(c, text="start")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)   
        self.label.bind("<Button-1>",self.label_click)
        self.running = False

    def label_click(self,event):
        if not self.running:
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.minutes = 5
        self.sec = 0
        self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        self.sec -= 1
        if self.sec < 0:
            self.sec = 59
            self.minutes -=1
        if self.minutes >= 0 and self.sec >= 0:
            self.label.configure(text = "{0}:{1:02}".format(self.minutes, self.sec))
            self.after(1000, self.tick)
        else:
            self.label.configure(text="start")
            self.running = False

exp_timer().mainloop()
```

In particular:

- You were not always using `self` when referring to `minutes` and `sec`
- You had no "loop" to do the count-down (that's what the call to `after` is for)
- You were not controlling the state of the GUI very well, i.e. what was to happen if the lable was clicked twice.  That is what the `running` attribute I've added handles
- You were doing very odd things with your `my_label_timer` function, you can't call a two parameter function with one parameter at a time.
- You had a few logic errors in your minutes/seconds decrementing code

Comment: Thanks a lot my way was garbage compared to this, much neater and easier to understand thank you. Awesome, thank you for including the In particular part!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Quite right, didn't hang around for the whole 5 minutes to test it... fixed!